# After Geoserver 2.8.2 Setup

Tags: geoserver

I have set up Geoserver 2.8.2 and, i am getting error below when i try to see functions under data part like (Layer, Workspace, Storage, Layer Preview)

I have read about regional settings and i changed those as English, United Kingdom, but it doesnt work.

```
org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Exception in rendering component: [Component id = filterMatch]
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.renderComponent(Component.java:2725)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebComponent.onRender(WebComponent.java:62)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2517)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1440)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1603)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAssociatedMarkup(MarkupContainer.java:696)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.Panel.onComponentTagBody(Panel.java:114)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.renderComponent(Component.java:2686)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:1538)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2517)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1440)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1603)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1527)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onComponentTagBody(Form.java:1995)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.renderComponent(Component.java:2686)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:1538)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2517)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1440)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1603)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAssociatedMarkup(MarkupContainer.java:696)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.Panel.onComponentTagBody(Panel.java:114)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.renderComponent(Component.java:2686)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:1538)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2517)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1440)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1603)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1527)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.renderComponent(Component.java:2686)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:1538)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2517)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.autoAdd(MarkupContainer.java:229)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.resolver.MarkupInheritanceResolver.resolve(MarkupInheritanceResolver.java:66)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.resolver.ComponentResolvers.resolve(ComponentResolvers.java:81)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1444)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1603)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1527)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.renderComponent(Component.java:2686)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:1538)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2517)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.autoAdd(MarkupContainer.java:229)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.resolver.MarkupInheritanceResolver.resolve(MarkupInheritanceResolver.java:73)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.resolver.ComponentResolvers.resolve(ComponentResolvers.java:81)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1444)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAll(MarkupContainer.java:1554)
    at org.apache.wicket.Page.onRender(Page.java:1575)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2517)
    at org.apache.wicket.Page.renderPage(Page.java:913)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.respond(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:261)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.respond(AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.java:105)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.processEventsAndRespond(RequestCycle.java:1258)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.step(RequestCycle.java:1329)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.steps(RequestCycle.java:1436)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.request(RequestCycle.java:545)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doGet(WicketFilter.java:484)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketServlet.doGet(WicketServlet.java:138)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:159)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1093)
    at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:71)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:71)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:46)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
    at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerUserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerUserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:146)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:53)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:135)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
    at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:83)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
    at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:42)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:48)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
    at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:44)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
    at org.vfny.geoserver.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:109)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:360)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:726)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:206)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:828)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:514)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
    at org.mortbay.thread.BoundedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(BoundedThreadPool.java:450)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unmatched braces in the pattern.
    at java.text.MessageFormat.applyPattern(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.MessageFormat.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.wicket.model.StringResourceModel.getString(StringResourceModel.java:546)
    at org.apache.wicket.model.StringResourceModel.load(StringResourceModel.java:647)
    at org.apache.wicket.model.StringResourceModel.load(StringResourceModel.java:181)
    at org.apache.wicket.model.LoadableDetachableModel.getObject(LoadableDetachableModel.java:120)
    at org.apache.wicket.model.StringResourceModel$AssignmentWrapper.getObject(StringResourceModel.java:241)
    at org.apache.wicket.model.StringResourceModel$AssignmentWrapper.getObject(StringResourceModel.java:216)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.getDefaultModelObject(Component.java:1720)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.getDefaultModelObjectAsString(Component.java:1739)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.basic.Label.onComponentTagBody(Label.java:114)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.renderComponent(Component.java:2686)
    ... 138 more
```

Comment: is this on windows? if so which version? can you try United States instead of UK

Comment: Yes, Iam using windows7, and also I have tried US instead UK after your suggestion, Unfortunately it doesnt work.

Comment: I have uninstall all things and i have tried another way to setup. With tomcat and war file of geoserver setup, I have installed geoserver at the end i get the same error on chrome browser. Than i tried firefox, it is solved now on firefox. 
Thanks for your attention,
Gulnerman